# How to open raw file read/write with Java without JNI to bypass OS cache

Tags: java, fopen, file-writing

I need to open files with these flags in a Java application

```
(linux) O_RDWR, O_SYNC, O_DIRECT, O_EXCL
(windows) FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH
```

to bypass the OS cache.

Is there any way to do it without JNI and native libraries?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the whole `sun.nio.fs` package, including, but not limited to, `WindowsFileSystem`, `WindowsFileSystemProvider` and others. https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/tree/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs

Comment: Thank you @Polygnome is there a documentation website for this library? I didn't find it thought github